# Weblogic without their IDE?

Tags: java, ide, weblogic

I'm starting Java development at a place that uses Weblogic on their production and test servers.   I'd like to use Weblogic on my computer to develop my code.   It seems that Weblogic has a development environment where a personal web server/servlet container is tightly integrated with an Eclipse based IDE of theirs.

I think I might like to go that way eventually, but for right now I would like to keep using the IDE that I am used to.

Can someone point me to a tutorial or a book that would explain how to set up and use Weblogic that way on my computer?

For instance,  I would produce a WAR file with my own tools,  then stick it in a directory in Weblogic on my computer to run it and see how well it works.

Thanks

Comment: "I would like to keep using the IDE that I am used to". Sure, just update the question with your IDE.

Comment: What tools are you using to create your WAR file?

Comment: I'm use an ANT build.xml file with the Visual Slickedit IDE.   I discovered that WebLogic server is on my box ( new job ), I got their example server running, got my own sample JSP running and now I am trying to figure out how to set up a database resource in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have not already downloaded WebLogic I would suggest getting started with the Zip Distribution.  It is a smaller distribution than the full installer and you can get it up and running quickly.  Here's a YouTube demo of the Zip Distribution: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHX_ej3ajcI

WebLogic also has support for ANT and Maven, so if you are using those to build and package your applications then you can automate deployment with them as well.  Here's a demo and info on the WebLogic Maven Plugin: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GcwcGtz0dyc

I use IntelliJ to do development and use the Maven Plugin to deploy directly to WebLogic.

**Update**: here's a quick demo and overview of setting up WLS JDBC and JMS: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxddHY3hf3c

Comment: I've been trying to run the configure.sh on my Ubuntu box.  I can successfully echo MW_HOME.  While in MW_HOME I try running configure.sh with variations of  sh ./configure.sh and get told that MW_HOME is not set.  Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind, I opened the script and all it does is call another script which I ran manually.  Any tips on how to find docs and links for the examples would be appreciated.  I installed the examples, but I can't find docs about where to find them or how to run them.

Comment: Which examples are you referring to?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: LOL.  The examples of JSPs/servlet webapps that come with the full installation of WebLogic.   I found the supplemental zip file that has them.  I got them installed.  I can't get my WAR file to deploy.  I've put in several "autodeploy" dirs but the WARS don't unpack and get a 404 when I go to the paths I mapped them to in my weblogic.xml

Answer (score 1):

One option may be to use [Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Home) to help manage the deployment from a Maven build via the [Cargo Maven plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin).  Combine that with [JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/) and you'll have a nice, state-of-the-art development solution.